# Reversing order of elements in multidimensional array

Tags: c#, arrays

I have an array with elemnents in order 1,2,3,4,5 and I would need to reverse it so it will be 5,4,3,2,1.
What about the following pseudo code? Is here not an easier way
**EDIT: I Am sorry I thought multidimensional array**

```
    someclass [,] temporaryArray=new someclass [ArrayLenght,ArrayLenght];


   //for each dimension then
    for(int I=0;I<ArrayLenghtOfDimension;I++)
    {
      temporaryArray[ArrayLenghtOfDimension-I]=Array[I];

    }

    Array=temporaryArray;
```

Comment: Do you need to store the reversed array or simply iterate over the array backwards?

Answer (score 4):

The array base class has a Reverse() extension method built in

```
int[] originalArray = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
int[] reversedArray = originalArray.Reverse().ToArray();
```

Note that the Reverse method returns IEnumerable, so you need to call ToArray() on the result.

And if you need to just iterate over the elements in the array, then all you need is

```
foreach (int element in originalArray.Reverse())
                Console.WriteLine(element);
```

Oops - Reverse is on IEnumerable, not Array, so you can use that with any collection.

```
IEnumerable<int> IEnumerableInt = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3 };
int[] reversedArray2 = IEnumerableInt.Reverse().ToArray();
```

Comment: Thanks! BTW what if the array is multidimensional?

Comment: @Tomas you are changing your requirements.

Comment: If you have int[][] Foo and call Reverse() on Foo, I'm pretty sure that'll give you the array of arrays in Reverse order so with new int[][] { new int[] { 1, 2, 3 }, new int[] { 4, 5, 6 } }; calling Reverse would give you an IEnumerable of two int[] arrays, the first being 4, 5, 6, the second being 1, 2, 3

Comment: I am sorry, my question was meant to multidimensional arrays..sorry for confusion

Comment: See my new answer for a multi-dimensional array

Comment: @Adam but an array object has no Reverse method. :)

Comment: For clarity, IEnumerablt<T> has a reverse method, but you have to be using C# 3.0, which I believe was released with .NET 3.5

Answer (score 2):

Yes there is fast solution exists in .net

```
int[] values = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };

Array.Reverse(values);
```

Your array is reversed. so you can iterate through it

```
foreach (int i in values)
{
    Response.Write(i.ToString());
}
```

the above code will display
**54321**

It will also work for string[], char[] or other type of arrays

Answer (score 2):

Event though the `Array` class has [`Reverse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.reverse.aspx) methods defined:

```
Array.Reverse(originalArray); // original array is now reversed
```

If all you need to do is iterate backwards over it do the following:

```
for(int I= ArrayLength - 1; I >= 0; I--)
{

}
```

This avoid re-allocating memory for the reversed array.

Answer (score 1):

`Array.Reverse` is the best way to do this. Do you care about order of the elements at all? If so,then you can do the following.

```
 int[] originalArray = new int[] { 10, 2, 13, 4, 5 };
 int[] descOrderedArray = originalArray.OrderByDescending(i => i).ToArray();
 int[] ascOrderedArray =   originalArray.OrderBy(i => i).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

For a multi-dimensional array it's the same idea

```
int[][] multiDimArray = new int[][] { new int[] { 1, 2, 3 }, new int[] { 4, 5, 6 } };
int[][] reversedMultiArray = multiDimArray.Reverse().ToArray();
```

produces an array of two arrays that is: {4, 5, 6}, {1, 2, 3}

Comment: An array object has no Reverse method :)

Comment: It does in C# 3 :-)   It's an Extension method on IEnumerable<T>

Comment: Oops, sorry I was looking in 2.0

Comment: Well but this is not like [,]

Comment: int[,] is a 2-dimensional matrix.  How exactly are you expecting to "reverse" that?  Your question said that you wanted to reverse elements 1,2,3,4,5 to 5,4,3,2,1.  It makes no sense to do that with a 2-dimensional matrix.  Please clarify exactly what you're trying to do.

Comment: A small clarification on this old post, to help those who are searching: according to MSFT, `int[,]` is a multidimensional array and `int[] []` is a jagged array or an array of arrays.